# remote process with wmi, get return value

Tags: process, wmi, return-value

the following code connects to a remote pc and execute the process try.exe located on that pc.

```
string prcToRun = "\"C:\\try.exe\" \"";;
object[] theProcessToRun = { prcToRun };    
ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
theConnection.Username = "domain\\user";
theConnection.Password = "password.";
ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\192.168.1.1\\root\\cimv2", theConnection);
ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());        
theScope.Connect();
theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
```

It works fine, because "try.exe" does what I expect. However I'd like to obtain back the result of try.exe execution. Is it possibile with wmi? At least I need to know when try.exe ends, but it would be better return a value. I know it would be possibile with psexec, but I can't use it.

Thank you

Comment: Why not make an HTTP request from `try.exe`? You could pass a token to `try.exe` (different for each invokation on each PC) use the pc's MAC address, the current time

Comment: (oops, timeout).... the token, and the results of execution as querystring parameters back to an HTTP server where your code is running.